# Strange behavior when changing direction using RigidBody.AddRelativeForce

Tags: unity-game-engine

My character is (temporally) a cube. The cube is mapped with a C# script and Rigid Body component.

I use the following code in `Update()` to change my character (which is a rigid body)'s direction:

```
void Update () {
  rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(transform.right * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
    rigidbody.velocity = transform.right* rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
  }
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
    rigidbody.velocity = transform.right* rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
  }
}
```

The behavior becomes: http://youtu.be/NYPNgAulc-k

I expect the character turns 90 degree left / right and start accelerating exactly in its new direction. But now, after it turns, it accelerates in curve. See the above video for more information.

What did I miss?

---

**UPDATE (30 Jan):** Changed `transform.right` to `transform.forward` and remove velocity changing lines:

```
void Update () {
  rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
  }
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
  }
}
```

which results in moving in another direction (thus I change the camera pointing vector) & not changing direction when Left or Right arrow; only the Runner object rotates.

Demo video: http://youtu.be/UVG6l14oyjw

---

**UPDATE (4 Feb):** Applied @Roboto's answer below, with some modifications made:

```
void Update () {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
       transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
       rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
       rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
     }
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
       transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
       rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
       rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
     }
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    // Physics stuff should be done inside FixedUpdate :)
    rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

Turning is finally okay. I have an extra function that makes the character jump. In `Update()`, I added:

```
if ((Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || isTouched) && isOnGround) {
    isOnGround = false; 
    rigidbody.AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

where `isOnGround` is a boolean, which sets to true when the Runner object touches the ground. However, before it leaves the ground, it moves along Z axis. When the unit leaves the ground, it slides to X-Z axis. This part of updated question is asked separately: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21542507/188331).

Note: Given that the Runner object has mass of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html), `Transform.forward`:

```
The blue axis of the transform in world space.
```

World space, so we want to use `AddForce` instead of `AddRelativeForce`, since `AddRelativeForce` would use the local coordinate system to add the force.

So this works:

```
void Update () {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
       transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
     }
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
       transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
     }
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    // Physics stuff should be done inside FixedUpdate :)
    rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new in Unity. How should I modify the codes to achieve my expected behavior ?

Comment: After changing to `transform.forward`, the box moves left from start instead of moving forward.

Comment: Yes, your updated answer leads me to a correct way. See my question update. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Maybe I will ask my further question in a new question.