# Incorrect moving direction when object in midair

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Extending my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21446930/188331), my character is (temporally) a cube. The cube is mapped with a C# script and Rigid Body component.

I use the following code to change my character (which is a rigid body)'s direction:

```
public float speed = 0;
public Vector3 jumpHeight = new Vector3();
public bool isOnGround = true

void Update () {
    bool isTouched = false;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        isTouched = true;
    }
    if ((Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || isTouched) && isOnGround) {
        isOnGround = false; 
        rigidbody.AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (isOnGround) {
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

where `isOnGround` is a boolean, which sets to true when the Runner object touches the ground. However, before it leaves the ground, it moves along Z axis. When the unit leaves the ground, it slides to X-Z axis. What did I miss?

Note: Given that the Runner object has mass of 3.

Comment: What do you set `jumpHeight` to? *(which is a very misleading name btw, given that it's a velocity vector, not a height)*

Comment: `jumpHeight` is set to `Vector3(1,7,0)`

Answer (score 0):

If the `jumpHeight` is set to `Vector3(0,7,0)`, the problem is gone and the Runner object is jumping aligned with axes.